# Java - split an input stream with every 4th space

Tags: java, split, inputstream, tokenize

I want to tokenize an inputstream with every 4th space. So that whenever I call something like next(), it returns me the 4 words from the line... if 4 words are not there in the input stream as it has reached to its end then return whatever is left in the input stream

### Edited

I am looking for a regex...

Comment: What's wrong with a nested loop that gets four tokens in each iteration?

Comment: What did you try so far that didn't work?

Comment: What do you consider a space? Do you mean the space character or whitespace in general?

Comment: using an regex (ie. .*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s) to split de string?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the bytes onto the end of a String using next(), make a count variable for how many words were already found, and check if that byte is a space (' '). Then return the String at the end of the method. So that way you get the bytes that were sent and also remove them from the stream from the next() method.